# How to find a matrix representation of a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Im stuck in this exercise where i have to find the matrix representation of a linear transformation.

Let $P_3(\mathbb{C})$ be a complex vector space of complex polynomial of degree $\leq2$.

Let $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}, \alpha\neq\beta$ and consider $L:P_3(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2$ given by

$L(p)=
\begin{pmatrix}
p(\alpha)\\
p(\beta)\\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $p\in P_3(\mathbb{C})$

Consider the basis

$\mathcal{V}=(1,X,X^2)$ for $P_3(\mathbb{C})$ and the standardbasis $\mathcal{E}=(e_1,e_2)$ for $\mathbb{C^2}$

Find the matrix representation 
${}_{\mathcal{E}}[L]_{\mathcal{V}}$
for $L$ according to $\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{E}$.

I dont know if this is correct, but i have reached the following

$_{\mathcal{E}}{[L]}_{\mathcal{V}}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
[L(1)]_\mathcal{E} & [L(X)]_\mathcal{E} & [L(X^2)]_\mathcal{E} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{pmatrix}
\in Mat_{2,3}(\mathbb{C})$

I know I have to find $[L(1)]_\mathcal{E},  [L(X)]_\mathcal{E},[L(X^2)]_\mathcal{E}$, but i dont know how to do it.

Comment: The algorithm is "evaluate the operator in the elements of the domain basis, write the results as combinations of the codomain basis, and put the coefficients in the columns of a matrix".

Comment: Yes, it do, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v_0(x) = 1, v_1(x) = x, v_2(x) = x^2$.

Then $L(a v_0 + b v_1 + c v_2 ) = (a+b\alpha + c \alpha^2)e_1+ (a+b\beta+ c \beta^2)e_2 $.

So $(a,b,c)$ in the $v_0,v_1,v_2$ basis maps to $(a+b\alpha + c \alpha^2, a+b\beta+ c \beta^2)$ is the $e_1,e_2$ basis. What is the matrix that does this mapping?

You need to fill in the matrix so that the following makes sense:

$\begin{bmatrix} a+b\alpha + c \alpha^2 \\ a+b\beta+ c \beta^2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} ? & ? & ? \\ ? & ? & ?\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: We just have to transpose what (a,b,c) in the v0, v1, v2 basis maps to and then take the variables out? right? So the matrix will look like this row 1 is 1 - \alpha - \alpha^2 and row 2 is 1 - \beta - \beta^2. Sorry for the bad notation.

Comment: See my addition.

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix} a+b\alpha + c \alpha^2 \\ a+b\beta+ c \beta^2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \alpha & \alpha^2 \\ 1 & \beta & \beta^2\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: That is correct :-).

Comment: Thanks for the help :)